# Why can I not use array definition in a method call?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code:

```
char[] c = {','};
string[] s = someString.Split(c, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I want to rewrite it as:

```
string[] s = someString.Split({ ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but that gives a syntax error. Why can I not use `{ ',' }` in a method call?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22605955/993547) one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string[] s = someString.Split(new [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of char array with the new keyword: new [] {','} or use another Split version and filter empty string afterwards:

```
var s = someString.Split(',').Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).ToArray();
```